# upgrade php version in xampp (using ubuntu 12.04 32 bit)

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04 32 bit and current version of php is 5.4.7 and i want it to upgrade to version 5.6 atleast.
I have not much idea about xampp and php
help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 32 bit. i am not using windows.

Comment: did you find a solution? , I am still looking :)